# Check after random sample in python

Tags: python, list, random

This is my first little project and first question so sorry for the formatting. I have two lists containing recipe names as strings. I want to ask the user how many meals from each list they want and then take a random selection.

I then want to check if a meal was chosen by the selection and display the price of the meal which I would store in a variable.

My idea was to add the random sample to a new list and to check the contents via an if in statement. If the recipe was inside the new list then it would print the variable containing the price.

When I check the new list for the recipe however, it doesn't think it is in the list. Is there something I've missed or a better way to do this? Thank you.

My code so far:

```
import random
Vegetarian = ["Jungle Curry", "Chickpea Curry", "Dhal", "Buddha Bowl", 
"Chickpea Salad", "Lazy Noodles", "Fry Up"]
Meat = ["Chilli", "Butter Chicken", "Lamb and Hummus"]

v = int(raw_input("How many vegetarian meals this week? > "))
m = int(raw_input("How many meaty meals? > "))

Veg1 = random.sample(Vegetarian, v)
Meat2 = random.sample(Meat, m)

veg_week = []
meat_week = []

veg_week.append(Veg1)
meat_week.append(Meat2)

jungle_curry = 10
chickpea_curry = 10

if "Jungle Curry" and "Chickpea Curry" in veg_week:
    print jungle_curry + chickpea_curry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would have done it like this

```
import random

Vegetarian = ["Jungle Curry", "Chickpea Curry", "Dhal", "Buddha Bowl",
          "Chickpea Salad", "Lazy Noodles", "Fry Up"]
Meat = ["Chilli", "Butter Chicken", "Lamb and Hummus"]

v = int(raw_input("How many vegetarian meals this week? > "))
m = int(raw_input("How many meaty meals? > "))

Veg1 = random.sample(Vegetarian, v)
Meat2 = random.sample(Meat, m)

veg_week = []
meat_week = []

veg_week.append(Veg1)
meat_week.append(Meat2)

# put the prices of each in the list too 
Vegetarian_price = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Meat_price = [20, 20, 20]

v_cost = 0
m_cost = 0
for i in range(len(Veg1)):
    v_cost += Vegetarian_price[Vegetarian.index(Veg1[i])]

for i in range(len(Meat2)):
    m_cost += Meat_price[Meat.index(Meat2[i])]

print v_cost,m_cost
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Please could you explain the way it assigns the values in the price list to the original recipe list? From my understanding, it uses the length of Veg1 list as an integer, then I don't follow how it interacts with the other 2 lists.

Comment: The vegetarian food list and the vegiterian_cost list are in order, that means the first price for the first food, so take the name and see index of the food in vegetarian list and take that and see in cost and that's its price, and add it there are more than one

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes, let's go through them:

- The result of `random.sample` is a list; when you call veg_week.append(Veg1', you are creating a list of lists.
- After this, you are assigning the value `10` to  `jungle_curry` and `chickpea_curry`
- Then, you are checking if both `"Jungle Curry"` and `"Chickpea Curry"` are in the selected sample; maybe you want to check if these are in this week's menu one by one?

This should work better:

```
import random

Vegetarian = ["Jungle Curry", "Chickpea Curry", "Dhal", "Buddha Bowl", 
"Chickpea Salad", "Lazy Noodles", "Fry Up"]
Meat = ["Chilli", "Butter Chicken", "Lamb and Hummus"]

v = int(input("How many vegetarian meals this week? > "))
m = int(input("How many meaty meals? > "))

Veg1 = random.sample(Vegetarian, v)
Meat2 = random.sample(Meat, m)

if "Jungle Curry" and "Chickpea Curry" in veg1:
    print(jungle_curry + chickpea_curry)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! So if I set a variable for each recipe to have its price e.g.
    jungle_curry = 10
    chickpea_curry = 12
etc. Could I then add the sum of the random sample without a lot of if-in statements?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do it. Try it, that's the best way to learn, and don't hesitate to ask another question if you get stuck.